# agregar animacion a un titulo (maquina de escribir)

Tags: html, css

hola tengo un titulo en `html` el cual quisiera agregarle una animación como el de la maquina de escribir

```html
<h1>nuestro aporte<h1>:
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
body { 
 font-family: monospace; 
 background: tomato;
}
.contenedor {
 margin: auto;
 display: table;
}

h1 { 
 position: relative; 
 float: left;
 background: tomato;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2.5em;
}

h1 span {
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:0;
    background: tomato;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    animation: escribir 5s steps(30) infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes escribir {
    from { width: 100% }
    to { width:0 }
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
   <h1>Nuestro aporte.<span>&#160;</span></h1>
  </div>
```

Comment: gracias amigo. pero tengo una imagen de fondo la cual no me permita hacer. este proceso!

Comment: Agrega una explicación del código para mejorar la calidad de la respuesta por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi propuesta: para una animación al estilo maquina de escribir puedes utilizar SVG de esta manera:

En SVG puedes utilizar texto en un trazado:

```
<text stroke="#000000" font-size="14">
  <textPath xlink:href="#elTrazado">
        Nuestro aporte
  </textPath>
</text>
```

donde `#elTrazado` es el trazado utilizado

El trazado utilizado es muy sencillo: una línea que empieza en el punto de coordenadas 10,30 y continua con una línea horizontal de 80 unidades de larga: `d="M10,30h80"`. Si lo dejo de esta manera puedes ver todo el texto.

Para un efecto de maquina de escribir voy a animar la linea horizontal ( el trazado ) desde una largada de 0 unidades `M10,30h0` hasta una largada de 80 unidades `M10,30h80`. esto lo puedes hacer utilizando animaciones SMIL (mira el valor del atributo values):

```
   <path id="elTrazado" d="M10,30h80" >
      <animate 
       attributeName="d"
       attributeType="XML"
       values="M10,30h0;
               M10,30h80;"
       dur="2s"/>
    </path>
```

A continuación puedes ver un ejemplo:

```css
body{
background:url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516642898673-edd1ced08e87?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&cs=tinysrgb&w=400&fit=max&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjE0NTg5fQ);background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 50">
  <defs>
    <path id="elTrazado" d="M10,30h80" >
      <animate 
       attributeName="d"
       attributeType="XML"
       values="M10,30h0;
               M10,30h80;"
       dur="2s"/>
    </path>
  </defs>
  <text stroke="#000000" font-size="14">
      <textPath xlink:href="#elTrazado">
            Nuestro aporte
      </textPath>
    </text>
</svg>
```